# Can "for" work as "compared to"?

Tags: meaning

> **Human capital is vastly increased** 
>   Crowdsourcing brings people together to solve problems. Yet far fewer than one per cent of the world’s population is involved. We need expand human capital. Most of the world not have access to the education afforded a small minority. **For every Albert Einstein, Yo-Yo Ma or Barack Obama who has educational opportunities, uncountable others do not.** This squandering of talent translates into reduced economic output and a smaller pool of problem solvers. The net opens the gates education to anyone with a computer. A motivated teen anywhere on the planet can walk through the world’s knowledge -- from the webs of Wikipedia to the curriculum of MIT’s OpenCourseWare. The new human capital will serve us well when we confront existential threats we’ve never imagined before.

A paragraph from [the article *Six ways the internet will save civilisation* by *David Eagleman* from *Wired.co.uk*](http://www.wired.co.uk/magazine/archive/2010/12/start/apocalypse-no)

In Korea, there's an aptitude test for university admission every year, and as for English test various texts from the articles, books, etc are processed and given as questions. A quantity of texts are in advance chosen as possible questions and published as a textbook for students. One of which is me and so I happened to face the paragraph above in the class, whose translation confused me--the very one of the bold sentence; the sentence was translated into Korean as, to put it back in English,

> "**?Compared to** every person like Albert Einstein, Yo-Yo Ma, or Barack Obama who has educational opportunities, there are uncountable others who never get the chance."

Whereupon I was confused why the *for* was translated into *compared to*.

Does the *for* really mean *compared to* in the context? If so, how? As far as I know, there's no such meaning for *for* in the dictionary. This may be a ludicrous question for you, native speakers, but for me, it's rather doubtful. I cannot know how to interpret the *for*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example cited, every [*person*] from a list of **educated persons**, corresponds to *uncountable others* in another implied list of **uneducated persons**, so [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for) definition 8.0 below seems to be the closest definition for the correspondence, and "*in contrast to*" to might be a better substitute to capture the meaning of the correspondence:

> *for*
>
> 8.0 In place of or in exchange for:
>
> ***In contrast to*** every Albert Einstein, Yo-Yo Ma or Barack Obama who has educational opportunities, uncountable others do not.
>
> *contrast:*
>
> 1.3 [IN SINGULAR] A thing or person having qualities noticeably different from another:

Every name on the educated persons list is *exchanged for* uncountable others on the uneducated person list, and the qualities of their education are noticeably different.

---

In the English language, *[for](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for)* does a lot of different work:

> From ODO preposition
>
> 1.0 In support of or in favor of (a person or policy):
>   *they voted for independence in a referendum*
>
> 2.0 Affecting, with regard to, or in respect of:
>   *she is responsible for the efficient running of their department the demand for money*
>
> 3.0 On behalf of or to the benefit of:
>   *I got a present for you*
>
> 3.1 Employed by:
>   *she is a tutor for the Open University*
>
> 4.0 Having (the thing mentioned) as a purpose or function:
>   *networks for the exchange of information*
>
> 5.0 Having (the thing mentioned) as a reason or cause:
>   *Aileen is proud of her family for their support*
>
> 6.0 Having (the place mentioned) as a destination:
>   *they are leaving for London tomorrow*
>
> 7.0 Representing (the thing mentioned):
>   *the ‘F’ is for Fascinating*
>
> 8.0 In place of or in exchange for:
>   *will you swap these two bottles for that one?*
>
> 8.1 Charged as (a price):
>   *copies are available for £1.20*
>
> 9.0 In relation to the expected norm of:
>   *she was tall for her age*
>
> 10.0 Indicating the length of (a period of time):
>   *he was jailed for 12 years*
>
> 11.0 Indicating the extent of (a distance):
>   *he crawled for 300 yards*
>
> 12.0 Indicating an occasion in a series:
>   *the camcorder failed for the third time*
>
> conjunction
>
> literary Because; since:
>   *he felt guilty, for he knew that he bore a share of responsibility for Fanny’s death*

Answer (score 0):

In your example, *for* is used to relate quantities of people with "educational opportunities" to those that do not have these opportunities (as a ratio, in this case 1:uncountably many), so I don't think *compared to* is a good substitute. To me, *compared to* implies an actual comparison between the people in the two categories, e.g.: "*Compared to Albert Einstein, Yo-Yo Ma or Barack Obama, most people of the world haven't received the same educational opportunities as they have.*"